# Why are my windows highlighted when I first open tmux?

Tags: tmux

Sometimes after having been away from my computer for a while, when I open tmux all the windows in a session have sort of a background highlight:

[image]

Once I cycle through them, it disappears, and only the active window has an asterisk:

[image]

Why does this happen, and is it possible fix it so the window labels never have a highlighted background?

Comment: It's illegible.You edit and rewtite your images.

Comment: Generally, it is because a bell has been triggered in that window or pane...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `man tmux':

```
 STATUS LINE
 [...]
 By default, the window list shows the index, name and (if
 any) flag of the windows present in the current session in ascending
 numerical order.  It may be customised with the window-status-format and
 window-status-current-format options.  The flag is one of the following
 symbols appended to the window name:

       Symbol    Meaning
       *         Denotes the current window.
       -         Marks the last window (previously selected).
       #         Window is monitored and activity has been detected.
       !         A bell has occurred in the window.
       ~         The window has been silent for the monitor-silence
                 interval.
       Z         The window's active pane is zoomed.

 The # symbol relates to the monitor-activity window option.  The window
 name is printed in inverted colours if an alert (bell, activity or
 silence) is present.
```

Since you didn't provide your `.tmux.conf`, it is hard to tell what triggers the alert.  Try `C-b : set-option -g monitor-activity off; set-option -g monitor-silence 0; set-option -g bell-action none` and test if the problem persists.  You could also forcefully disable the highlighting by adding these lines to your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set window-status-activity-style none
set window-status-bell-style none
```